# How to get a specific value in a json string in python 3.6

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to get a certain value in a string of json but I can't figure out how exactly to do it. I don't want to convert it into a string and strip / replace the unwanted pieces because then I won't be able to get the other values. My current code is:

```
    username = "Dextication"
    url = f"https://minecraft-statistic.net/api/player/info/{username}/"
    response = requests.get(url)
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    print(json_data)
```

Edit:
     when I run this, `json.data = "{"status":"ok","data":{"online":0,"total_time_play":46990,"last_play":1513960562,"license":1,"name":"Dextication","uuid":"74d57a754855410c90b3d51bc99b8beb"}}"`
I would like to only print the value: 46990

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking. Do you just want any values from the json response? If yes, just access them via their keys. `json.loads() `returns a dictionary. You can use all methods of `dict` then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code

```
import json, requests

username = "Dextication"
url = f"https://minecraft-statistic.net/api/player/info/{username}/"
response = requests.get(url)
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
result = json_data['data']['total_time_play']
print (result)
```